# Python nested list within a nested list without looping

Tags: python, nested-lists

I want to add a dictionary to a nested list within a nested list.

so;

```
['master_list 1', ['list 1', ['sub_list 1']], ['list 2'], ['list 3']]
```

would end up like;

```
['master_list_1', ['list_1', ['sub_list_1',{key_1:value_1}]], ['list_2'], ['list_3']]
```

I know the exact position within the lists that I want to add the dictionary, so can I add the dictionary without looping through other lists?

I have got as far as

```
master_list[0].append(list_1)
```

but I can't find out how to call the lower lists.

Comment: Sorry, found it.

    master_list[1][1][1].append(dict_1)

Answer (score 3):

```
master_list[1][1].append({key_1:value_1})
```